# What does it mean to change tense to past in precis writing

Tags: comprehension

I read the rules of precis writing. One rule states:

> **It should be written in the third person and past tense.**

(*Source : https://uogenglish.wordpress.com/english-lecture-notes/eng-102/precis-writing/*)

Can someone explain this point to me? How to change into past tense. I went through different precis writing examples(in a book) but tense was same as that in original paragraph.

Comment: That webpage says that, in a précis "universal truth[s]" should be written in the present tense–which is why the sample précis on that page uses non-past tenses.

Answer (score 1):

The most common case where this rule applies is when referring to the author of the passage the precis is about.  You should use the third-person, meaning either "he" or "she", "the writer", "the author", or the actual name, but never "I" or "you".  For example:

> In his most famous work, ["Do not go gentle into that good night"](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/do-not-go-gentle-good-night), the poet Dylan Thomas ...

The second part of the rule says that verbs discussing the language of the passage should be in the past tense, for example "the author *said*" not "the author *says*".  *However*, this rule makes little sense to me, since it's common to use the present tense when summarizing a written work.

For example, here is a quote from [a discussion](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-meaning-of-the-poem-Do-Not-Go-Gentle-Into-That-Good-Night-1) of of Dylan Thomas' poem:

> [The poem] **is** a strong invocation for us to live boldly and to fight. It **implores** us to not just "go gentle into that good night," but to rage against it. Even at the end of life, when "grave men" are near death, the poem **instructs** us to burn with life.

It's *possible* that the rule for an actual, formal precis is more strict, but I feel using the past tense (i.e., "The poem **was** a strong invocation for us to live boldly, etc.") is not natural English.

However, it is common to use the past tense when talking about the *author's* actions, for example:

> Dylan Thomas **wrote** "Do Not Go Gentle" as a response to his father's failing health.

But this makes sense, since action happened in the past.  When talking about the language of the work itself, it's more common to use the present tense, since the words exist in a sort of "timeless" state.